# Discord Python Command Arguments

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a command where the second argument is what the bot will actually do

`!haha kick, !haha ban, !haha test`

so I have

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def haha(ctx, arg):
    channel = bot.get_channel(591059696622895117)
    try:
        if (arg == "kick"):
            #kick 
        elif (arg == "ban"):
            #ban
    except:
        await channel.send("Error processing your request!")
        pass
```

however I run into an error when I run `!haha` since it's missing arguments, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument, It's a feature, not a bug.
You can handle it with command_error event.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send("Your command isn't right!\n Read the help")
  else:
    raise error
```